# I see screen on centos 7 after i change resolution

Tags: linux, centos, redhat-enterprise-linux, centos-7

I need to your help emergency .after change resolution my system , restart it , after login its stuck in black screen . . i dont know which part of system change it . plz help me. pc with 4k monitor connecting through display port, and with installed centos 7 , natively all work perfect, when i want to try change resolution to full hd , and when i login and see full black screen , and i nothing can do.
I tried many decisions for 1920x1080 i think problem that they solve with hdmi connection, that all solve is for hdmi and full hd resolution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: , how i can return my previous setting resolution or return to default condition my centos 7?